# Erratic Cursor: Laptop Touchpad Driver?

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, dell

I'm experiencing a horribly erratic, bouncy/shaky cursor in Ubuntu, but not in Windows.  It's a Dell Latitude E6230 laptop.  I was going to replace the touchpad until I discovered I wasn't having the problem in Windows.  Might this be a driver issue? Is there a touchpad/mouse driver for Ubuntu that might remedy this problem? I have the same problem while using other Linux distros too on this laptop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it happens if your screen has a touch option and it’s broken. Use

```
xinput
```

to find out the input device ID of your touch screen or touch pad and

```
xinput disable [ID]
```

to disable it.

Comment: and enable it back with,
xinput enable [ID]